# Trigger Pi to Capture Image From Other Pi Using GPIO

Tags: python, triggers, camera

I want to capture images from two Pi Cameras at the same time.
1 camera is connected to Pi1 (Master) and 1 camera to Pi2 (Slave).
I want to give command from Master pi and it will trigger the pin on Slave.
GPIO of 5V and Gnd are connected to each other.
For Master, GPIO 18 is connected to GPIO 23 of Slave

What I plan to do: Run code from Master -> Images taken from Master and Slave -> Show the images

Below is my code capture_images.py for the Master.

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray  
from picamera import PiCamera  
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  
import numpy
import readchar  
import datetime  
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture  
camera = PiCamera()  
camera.ISO = 100  
camera.resolution = (800, 480)  
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

# allow the camera to warmup  
time.sleep(0.1)  

# GPIO Setup  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.output(18, 0)

# grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
master_image = rawCapture.array
cv2.imwrite("master_image.png",master_image)

# trigger camera on slave and load
GPIO.output(18, 1)
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(18, 0)
time.sleep(1)

slave_image = cv2.imread('/home/pi/slave_image.png',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #To read image from Slave Pi

cv2.imshow("master_image",master_image)
cv2.imshow('/home/pi/slave_image.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

From Slave Pi I created a python code slave_camera.py as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python  


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import socket  
import time  
import picamera  

# PiCamera Setup  

#camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera = PiCamera()
camera.ISO = 100

# GPIO Setup  

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  #GPIO of Slave 


# Begin Loop  
try:  
  while True:  

  if GPIO.input(23):  

  camera.capture('/home/pi/slave_image.jpg')
  print('input from master on gpio 23, Picture taken!') 
  time.sleep(3)  

except KeyboardInterrupt: # trap a CTRL+C keyboard interrupt    
  GPIO.cleanup() # resets all GPIO ports used by this program
```

and added the script above at to /etc/rc.local:

```
python /home/pi/slave_camera.py &
```

I connected both Pi through SSHF so that I can access the image of Slave from Master.

When I run the code capture_images.py from Master, only image from Master camera is captured.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?
Thanks